# Ajax Paging/sorting in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 and trying to create ajax paging which i cant in the documentation i read that passing this

```
$this->Paginator->options(
                          array('update'=>'#box',
                                'evalScripts' => true,
                                'before' => $this->Js->get('#loaderIDast')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
                                'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loaderIDast')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
                          ))
```

in the view will make paginaton helper to create ajax link which in my case doesnt.
I am using jQuery engine here.

On digging the library files i came across that paginator is using the event function which is making this

```
jQuery("#link-969794460").bind("click", function (event) {jQuery.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {jQuery("#loaderIDast").fadeIn();}, complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {jQuery("#loaderIDast").fadeOut();}, dataType:"html", evalScripts:true, success:function (data, textStatus) {jQuery("#box").html(data);}, url:"\/admin\/user\/manage_user\/sort:User.name\/direction:asc"}); return false;});
```

and this is somehow not returned in event call.I dont know why any one have an idea what i am missing?

Regards
Himanshu Sharma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are example in the book [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html). Look for the Ajax Pagination section. Make sure to follow all of the directions and it'll work.

You need:

- The RequestHandler component to be loaded in your controller.
- The Js Helper to be loaded in your controller.
- You need to include jQuery in your view/layout.
- And you need to write the Js buffer (`$this->Js->writeBuffer()`) in your view/layout. It'd suggest putting this in your view unless you load the Js helper in your `AppController` because otherwise `$this->Js` won't be defined.

The example in the book uses jQuery and works.

Comment: I have done just that but to no use.Its in the documentation that $this->Paginator->options(
                          array('update'=>'#box',
will tell paginator to create ajax link which in my case it doesnt also the link which i am using on js helper are also generated as js link not ajax link.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget to add the $this->Paginator->numbers() after you tell pagination helper that you want a javascript link instead of plain html

```
    <?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
        'update' => '#content',
        'evalScripts' => true,
        'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
        'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but in my case the id of the div tag in layout file was wrong. It should be "content".