# AJAX pagination with CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

I'm struggling to get some ajax pagination with cakephp working. I've read the instructions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) and various other pages on the internet eg: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333358)

However I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught type error undefined is not a function
```

Which occurs on the `$(document).ready()` function generated by `$this->Js->writeBuffer()`.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

In my view `index.ctp` I set the paginator's options:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
        'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true)
);
```

Then carry on with the remainder of the view, in particular I render the table. The controller has fetched data to be displayed.

I output my pagination controls:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev();
echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
echo $this->Paginator->next();
```

At the end of my view I do:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

I have added the relevant helpers and components to my controller:

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('jquery'));

public $components = array(
    'Paginator',
    'RequestHandler'
);
```

In `default.ctp` I have included jquery by adding this to the end of the HTML (just before `</body>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

It looks it works in that it generated the relevant javascript and provides the id's for the links but clicking the links just works like normal.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included jQuery, or some other script calls `$.noConflict()`.

Comment: @AD7six You're right, I have updated my question to be more comprehensive.

Comment: The html output would be more relevant - but that's already enough information to give you an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Functions need to exist before they are called

> In default.ctp I have included jquery by adding this to the end of the HTML (just before `</body>`

Jquery needs to be loaded *before* it is used. Ensure that script tags appear in the rendered html in this order:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
... anything or nothing ...
<script> 
    $(document).ready(
        ...
```